# DSE Cassandra SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: cassandra

In DSE Cassandra, nodes I have added self signed certificate. Both the nodes are up but they are not able to communicate with other. I am getting the below exception:

```
ERROR [ACCEPT-/10.16.252.241] 2020-05-12 13:50:12,760  MessagingService.java:1412 - SSL handshake error for inbound connection from 6dd8b1d0[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=/10.16.252.209,port=52938,localport=7001]]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Comment: I hv performed certification addition steps from below url https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-trblshoot/doc/troubleshooting/secSSLnoStartOrexceptionsOnStart.html

Comment: What cipher suites are defined in the cassandra.yaml?  Also, Nate McCall has a great tutorial on this: https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2015/09/30/hardening-cassandra-step-by-step-part-1-server-to-server.html

Comment: Yes,Now i am getting below exception: ERROR [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.16.252.241-Gossip] 2020-05-14 03:24:04,068  OutboundTcpConnection.java:597 - SSL handshake error for outbound connection to 50b9770f[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=/10.16.252.241,port=7001,localport=38774]]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Comment: I am getting this msg in the system.log: Starting Encrypted Messaging Service on SSL port 7001 after that it is unable to do SSL Handshake.